# Why do stabilized IPW weights give the same estimates and SEs as unstabilized weights?

Tags: causality, propensity-scores, weighted-regression

In Cole & Hernán (2008), the authors mention that using stabilized weights can decrease the variance of the effect estimate. Regular inverse probability weights use the probability of being in the treatment actually assigned given the covariates in the denominator. Stabilized weights use the same denominator but use the marginal probability of being in the treatment actually assigned in the numerator.

However, when I follow these instructions and run a weighted regression use each set of weights, I get identical coefficient estimates and standard errors. Below is some R code demonstrating this.

```r
data("lalonde", package = "cobalt")

den.fit <- glm(treat ~ age + educ + race + married + nodegree + re74 + re75,
               data = lalonde, family = binomial)

num.fit <- glm(treat ~ 1,
               data = lalonde, family = binomial)

den.pred <- predict(den.fit, type = "response")

num.pred <- predict(num.fit, type = "response")

w <- ifelse(lalonde$treat == 1, 1/den.pred, 1/(1-den.pred))

sw <- ifelse(lalonde$treat == 1, num.pred/den.pred, (1-num.pred)/(1-den.pred))

c(w = sd(w)/mean(w), sw = sd(sw)/mean(sw))
#>        w       sw 
#> 1.370861 0.889870

fitw <- glm(re78 ~ treat, data = lalonde, weights = w)

fitsw <- glm(re78 ~ treat, data = lalonde, weights = sw)

all.equal(coef(fitw), coef(fitsw))
#> [1] TRUE
all.equal(sandwich::vcovHC(fitw, type = "HC3"), 
          sandwich::vcovHC(fitsw, type = "HC3"))
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The weights have different coefficients of variation, which some authors have said is directly related to the variance of the effect estimator, and yet both sets of weights produce identical results. Why is this, and why would the authors make this claim?

---

Cole, S. R., & Hernán, M. Á. (2008). Constructing Inverse Probability Weights for Marginal Structural Models. American Journal of Epidemiology, 168(6), 656–664. https://doi.org/10.1093/aje/kwn164

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because the marginal structural models you're fitting (objects `fitw` and `fitsw`) are so-called saturated models. For saturated models, using weight stabilization does not change the relative weights of outcomes in subgroups defined by the treatment levels, because in any subgroup the weight is multiplied by a factor that is constant within the subgroup (i.e. the numerator). Hope this helps!

You can find more details in section 6.1 of this excellent paper:

Robins JM, Hernán MÁ, Brumback B (2000) Marginal Structural Models and Causal Inference in Epidemiology. Epidemiology 11:550–560. https://doi.org/10.1097/00001648-200009000-00011

Comment: Thank you! I missed that in that paper. Welcome to CV!

Comment: Any good resource on how to use stabilized weights in matchit?